# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.MyComp.model.Image cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, sorting, collections, guava

I try to sort a List with the following code:

```
        List<Image> sortedImages = new LinkedList<Image>(inputImages);
        Collections.sort(sortedImages, imageScoreComparator);
```

and

```
class ImageScoreComparator implements Comparator<Image> {

    ImageScoreCalculator imageScoreCalculator;

    ImageScoreComparator() {
        this(new ImageScoreCalculator(Calendar.getInstance()));
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    ImageScoreComparator(ImageScoreCalculator imageScoreCalculator) {
        this.imageScoreCalculator = imageScoreCalculator;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Image image1, Image image2) {
        if (image2.isPromoted() && !image1.isPromoted()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (image1.isPromoted() && !image2.isPromoted()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return Double.compare(imageScoreCalculator.getScoreForImage(image1), imageScoreCalculator.getScoreForImage(image2));
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.MyComp.model.Image cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

This is how I init `imageScoreComparator`

```
imageScoreComparator = mock(ImageScoreComparator.class);
        when(imageScoreComparator.compare(image1, image2)).thenReturn(0);
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your `imageScoreComparator` variable is null. If the `Comparator` passed as the second parameter to `Collections.sort` is null, it does not treat that as an error; rather it will try to cast each item in the list to `Comparable`, sorting them according to their natural sort order, which won't work for these objects.

Make sure you're initializing the `imageScoreComparator` variable to something non-null.

Comment: Oh my. I didn't know that. What a stupid design decision to accept a null comparator! +1.

Comment: @user1065869 My answer is the same: make sure you're setting the Comparator variable to something non-null (before you use it).

Comment: is mocking not creating an instance?

Comment: @user1065869 I have no idea. Apparently not.